# How can I execute thousands of MySQL "INTO OUTFILE" queries in parallel on Linux?

Tags: mysql, bash

I am attempting to use xargs, but the file that I generated that has all of the queries that I need to execute is far too long to accept as a bash piped argument. I have a JSON file of all the queries I need to execute, but I have no clue how to execute them all in parallel. Any ideas?

Comment: One of the main reasons to use `xargs` is to run a program multiple times, taking as many arguments as possible from standard input for each run. How are you trying to run `xargs`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Since you have a JSON file, you need to Marshal it and then generate INSERT statement.

Just make sure that your MySQL server can handle so many concurrent requests. You maybe I/O than CPU bound

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'm not too worried about I/O given that the DB is distributed across four 1TB high-performance SSD's. The processor is a 6-core multi-threaded i7, so 8 threads *shouldn't* kill it. I could be wrong though. What did you mean by "Marshal it"?

Comment: Marshal meaning, to arrange in order.